# Debug Android app crash on startup without logcat or ACRA

Tags: android, crash, tablet

I'm having a problem where an app I'm developing is working on mobile devices (tested on 4 different devices), but crashing when I try to test it on my tablet. The tablet I'm using is a Tesco Hudl 2, which, although being a good quality low cost device, lacks adb drivers and so you can't debug apps through USB and get the Logcat data. The app was developed using Android Studio.

With other apps I have developed, I have just set up ACRA in the project so I can still get debug information from a crash. This time however, the app is crashing without any information from ACRA and so I'm not quite sure what is going wrong. I'm pretty sure I've set up ACRA correctly given that I've used it in several projects before and see nothing wrong this time. Can it be that whatever is going wrong is happening too early for ACRA to catch?

I have pulled out all the code from the activity so the only thing that happens in code is that ACRA gets initialized in the derived Application class (note that the crash exists without ACRA). The app also uses Google maps and a provider for search suggestions. If there is any code anyone wants to see just ask, but I'm unsure what exactly to post up since everything else was stripped out. So, does anyone have any idea on what I can do to solve this, or what tools I can use to catch whatever sort of errors happen so early in the apps lifecycle?

Thanks

Update with strange behaviour... Downloaded Crashlytics and it also did not catch the crash. I copied the project and removed every .java file except the Application, Activity and provider. The provider functions were empty (save for the return value of 0/false/null/whatever), the application class just initialized Crashlyitcs and the Activity class was empty. This then worked, I was even able to add in a lot of the code and get the google map to load.
Now if I do the same in my main project, except don't delete the .java files, the crash still happens. The classes in these files are not used so I have no idea how they can be causing the crash. Otherwise all the xml, gradle, resources are identical (except the package and app name). Very confusing...

Comment: We really need to see some code.

Comment: What exactly though? Manifest? Layouts? Styles/values? Given that it works ok on mobile, what would be the most likely culprits for it to fail on a tablet?

Comment: I was going to suggest using LogRabbit but if the device cannot be put into debug mode that won't help.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using one of the apps to view logcat on the device:

- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat
- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat

Also try using [Crashlytics](http://try.crashlytics.com/). Maybe it will catch your crash?

But yeah, it's possible to have a crash before any crash reporter (ACRA or Crashlytics) will have a chance to catch it.

And one more note, maybe there is a way to enabled ADB over WiFi.
Normally you would need to enable it via adb but maybe in case of this cheap and strange tablet, there is an option for that enabled in the ROM?

Comment: I have already tried the logging apps but they don't show any app info on the hudl. I could try crashlytics I guess

Comment: yeah. also, added a note about ADB over WiFi. check it out in developer options on the device

Comment: I've tried many ways to enable debugging, from usb to wifi to installing drivers to trick it into working but to no avail. Very frustrating that they don't supply a driver given that the tablet has a very good screen and -would- be very useful as a cheap dev device. Tesco may not be a tech company but they are one of the biggest retailers in the world so would surely have a large share of the  'cheap dev tablet' market if they made the driver...

Answer (score 0):

Ok! So it's 1am and I decided to have one final attempt to fix, which I think I did. In my manifest, I had things like

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        ...
```

for example, and while this worked fine on the mobiles, for some reason the Hudl required the complete package name, i.e. com.mypackage.MyActivity. Not sure why this is the case but it appears to have fixed the problem.